# ParametricPlot takes very long to produce an output

Tags: numerical-integration, parametric-functions

I need a parametric plot of a curve whose components are defined by:$$\left(\int_0^x\cos(f(t))dt,\int_0^x\sin(f(t))dt\right)$$ where $f(t)$ is an InterpolatingFunction (obtained from NDSolve). The Code I show below works fine, but depending on $f(t)$ can take very long to produce the output. 
Any suggestion to make it faster?...I mean, I am almost sure that the problem does not belong to ParametricPlot but to the way I define the integral with the variable extremum.

```
s = NDSolve[{y'[x] == g[x], g'[x] == -60 (1 - x) Cos[y[x]], y[0] == 0,g[0]== 1.2}, {y, g}, {x, 0, 1}];
f[x_] = Evaluate[y[x] /. s];
intcos[x_Real] := NIntegrate[Cos[f[t]], {t, 0, x}];
intsin[x_Real] := NIntegrate[Sin[f[t]], {t, 0, x}];
ParametricPlot[{intcos[x], intsin[x]}, {x, 0, 1}]
```

**Note** The code does not produce an output in mathematica 11, but work fine in mathematica 10, [but I am going to make another question about that](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/144642/parametricplot-does-not-work-in-mathematica-11-as-in-10).

Comment: Where is `f[t]`? How can we test it?

Comment: I added the information you need. Thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ParametricPlot does not work in Mathematica 11 as in 10](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/144642/parametricplot-does-not-work-in-mathematica-11-as-in-10)

Comment: I was asking two different things about the same code. I think the best was to open two questions.

Comment: Your both issues were answered by @Pillsy response, doesn't it?

Answer (score 2):

For this you already got an elegant [answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/144642/parametricplot-does-not-work-in-mathematica-11-as-in-10) from @Pillsy.

But here, I will propose an alternative approach using `Table` and `Thread`.

This is certainly faster than yours but not the one suggested by @Pillsy.

```
s = NDSolve[{y'[t] == g[t], g'[t] == -60 (1 - t) Cos[y[t]], y[0] == 0, g[0] == 1.2},
            {y, g}, {t, 0, 1}];

f[t_] = y[t] /. s[[1]];

intcos[x_Real] := NIntegrate[Cos[f[t]], {t, 0, x}];

intsin[x_Real] := NIntegrate[Sin[f[t]], {t, 0, x}];

incosdata = Table[intcos[x], {x, 0, 1, 0.02}];

insindata = Table[intsin[x], {x, 0, 1, 0.02}];

ListLinePlot[Thread[{incosdata, insindata}]]
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It can be quicker if you use parallel computing.

In:

```
Clear[s, x, y, g, f, xys]
s = NDSolve[{y'[x] == g[x], g'[x] == -60 (1 - x) Cos[y[x]], y[0] == 0,
     g[0] == 1.2}, {y, g}, {x, 0, 1}];
f[x_] = Evaluate[y[x] /. s] // First ;
intcos[x_Real] := NIntegrate[Cos[f[t]], {t, 0, x}];
intsin[x_Real] := NIntegrate[Sin[f[t]], {t, 0, x}];
xys = ParallelTable[{intcos[x], intsin[x]}, {x, 0, 1, 
    0.01}]; (*Time is 2.84873 seconds, 4 Wolfram Kernels*)

ListLinePlot[xys]
```

Out:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
$Version

(*  "11.1.1 for Mac OS X x86 (64-bit) (April 18, 2017)"  *)

s = NDSolve[{y'[x] == g[x], g'[x] == -60 (1 - x) Cos[y[x]],
     y[0] == 0, g[0] == 1.2}, {y, g}, {x, 0, 1}][[1]];

Clear[f, intcos, intsin]
```

Note the use of [`NumericQ`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/NumericQ.html) rather than [`Real`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Real.html).

```
Cases[{3.7, 2, Pi}, _Real]

(*  {3.7}  *)

Cases[{3.7, 2, Pi}, _?NumericQ]

(*  {3.7, 2, π}  *)


f[x_?NumericQ] := y[x] /. s

intcos[x_?NumericQ] :=
  NIntegrate[Cos[f[t]], {t, 0, x},
   Method -> {Automatic, "SymbolicProcessing" -> False}];
intsin[x_?NumericQ] :=
  NIntegrate[Sin[f[t]], {t, 0, x},
   Method -> {Automatic, "SymbolicProcessing" -> False}];

ParametricPlot[{intcos[x], intsin[x]}, {x, 0, 1},
   ImageSize -> Medium] // AbsoluteTiming // Column
```

[image]